# Using sqlite in multithreaded environment

Tags: multithreading, sqlite, transactions

I've been trying to wrap my head around SQLite docs about multithreading, but still not quite get it. Let say I have 2 threads that read and write from/to DB. My write consists of multiple sql statements, so I need wrap them in explicit transaction, something like this:

```
sqlite3_exec (myDb, "BEGIN TRANSACTION", 0, 0, 0);
// write stuff here
sqlite3_exec (myDb, "COMMIT TRANSACTION", 0, 0, 0);
```

First question: do I need wrap read operations in transaction the main requirement for me that until write transaction finishes it should not be possible to read half written data

Second: can I use one database connection in both threads? - looks like I can't because if both threads are writing to DB and therefore both open transactions second "BEGIN TRANSACTION" statement will fail.

So what is right approach here: Use own locking mechanism? Use one connection per thread? - what will happen in that case, should I worry about SQL_BUSY/SQL_LOCKED?

Thanks!

Comment: [Is SQLite threadsafe?](https://sqlite.org/faq.html#q6)

Answer (score 0):

When the two threads must not interfere with each other's transaction, you must use separate connections.

With concurrent transactions, it is possible to get conflicts, so you should set a busy timeout or install a busy handler.
If all connections are from threads in the same program, you can avoid conflicts by wrapping all transactions into a mutex.